# SQL MS Access Query to Get Text Value from Form Text Box

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a 'very' long query written through MS Access with lot of unions (around 30) and other dynamic variables.

Now, I need to insert a 'Where' clause in all those unions, and the where clause would be constant and generated through a form (selecting some options, I have written a vb code to create a string containing the where clause.

Is there any way I could use some variables in the SQL query so that the variable gets the where clause from the text result of the form action?

Illustrative: My Query

```
Select a,b,c,d from
   (select x as a,b,c,d from abc <where clause> union
    select y as a,b,c,d from abc <where clause> union
    select z as a,b,c,d from abc <where clause> union
    select p as a,b,c,d from abc <where clause>)
order by a
```

The  should be populated with the text box result which would look something like 'where b=1'

I thought of writing it in the VB code itself, but to numerous linebreaks and chaning nature of the queries, I do not want to manually keep adding " & _ at the end of each line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Navs

Answer (score 2):

You can write the WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE B=[Forms]![FormName]![FieldName]
```

so it gets the value from the form. But, if i understand it correctly, in the form there's not just the condition, but there's the whole where clause, that could be *'where b=1'* but it could also be *'where c=4'* or *'where a=2 and b=6'*?

I think there's not a perfect solution to this, you can't use plain Access but you have to write some VBA code, and you can generate the query string with something like this:

```
$src_query = "Select a,b,c from abc <where clause> union select ..."
$src_query = Replace($src_query,
                     "<where clause>",
                     [Forms]![FormName]![WhereClause])
```

then you just have to modify the query programmatically:

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("QueryName").SQL = $src_query
```

and now your query is ready to be executed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Exactly, the where clause could be dynamic with different fields added or taken out. Your second solution seems to fit the bill. But there is a problem I face--The query I have is very long (I use excel with formulas to create that query). But the query won't change. It will be the same once I lock the final logic. However, the current length restricts me from using a $src_query. Do you know any other means how I can put a long query in the format as I need to format it to suit the numerous line breaks.

Comment: Hi fthiella, Is there any way to assign a query file contents to a variable as string in access vb?

Comment: Hi, i think i don't understand what's the problem here... what is the problem with line breaks? and what do you mean by assign a query file contents? if you can explain i can help you better!

Comment: Sure--My query is spans 227 lines in query editor. I am facing trouble in assigning such a long query to a variable (in your explanation - $srcquery). I have to then manually add the " & _ at the end of each line. What I was meaning by assigning contents to a variable is that, can I have the query in a text file and assign the contents of a file to a variable using vb access. Hope I was able to explain a bit clearly. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you very much for your precious time helping me out.

Comment: Hi fthiella, Thank you for your timely help. With little homework, I found how to assign the contents of the text file to a variable. I was then able to change the variable with the code snippets you had given. Thank you so much again for the timely help. I would close this post as of now.

Comment: okay, now i understand more :) since the query is very long, it's easier to read the query from a text file, instead of coding it. I'm happy you've found how to do that, and I'm happy that my code snippets has helped you!

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `Where` clauses in a separate query, and not alter the original

```
Select * 
from MyQuery
Where (a=1 and b=7) or (c=3 and d="StackOverflow")
```

Answer (score 0):

With little homework, I found how to assign the contents of the text file to a variable. I was then able to change the variable with the code snippets 'Fthiella' had given.